How to clone folders/files permission from Ubuntu to another Ubuntu?
I have two Ubuntu systems, same version same script installed, on my public Ubuntu I did a mistake by changing permission of root.
I ran rescue system and run a script that reset ubuntu permission to default and root run successfully, but im still having problem with some scripts need specific permission like:
phpmyadmin, snappymail, cyberpanel, snappymail and smtp server, all of those script are exist on my old ubuntu and the old ubuntu have all scripts which exist in my public Ubuntu also path is same, so if there is a way to copy permission of folders/files from root path / to my public Ubuntu it will be nice to use.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It would be helpful to know what version of Ubuntu are you running. Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

I solved my problem from here => https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/142533-i-need-script-copy-permissions-files-folders-one-server-another-2.html
find / -type d -printf "%h/%f %m\n" >> /root/do-restore.sh

but i do small edit to cover files also,
find / -type d,f -printf "%h/%f %m\n" >> /root/do-restore.sh

Then copy the /root/do-restore.sh to the server you have accidentally changed the permissions , I would say a quick way would be cat the file ,run a while loop and do chmod something like
cat /root/do-restore.sh|while read IN
do
fn=`echo $IN|awk '{print $1}'`
per=`echo $IN|awk '{print $2}'`
chmod $per $fn
done

This code above putted in execuatable file run.sh

Glad you found something that worked for you, however there are several issues with the code in your answer - in particular it will screw up if any of the filenames (or paths) contain whitespace or other special characters. It would be more robust to output the mode first i.e. -printf '%m %h/%f\n' - then you can read back the mode and name unambiguously using while read -r mode filename; do chmod "$mode" "$filename"; done </root/do-restore.sh

Could you please make this in answer and write a script for the final solution?
